# Apiary doesn't render array[Object] clearly as an array

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary

The following syntax:

```
### List Webhooks [GET /webhooks]

+ Request
    + Headers
    
            Authorization: Bearer <API_KEY>
    
+ Response 200 (application/json)
    + Attributes (array[Webhook])
```

doesn't look like an array when it's rendered in Apiary. See below.

[image: How response is shown in Apiary]

Did something change?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the new Apiary Documentation renderer? Many issues with rendering Data Structures have been fixed on it. I just tried your example and it renders as expected. https://help.apiary.io/tools/interactive-documentation-v4/